# MultiMarkdown to HTML parser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, markdown

I have seen some Javascript parsers to convert Markdown to HTML. I am not able to find any that would do the same for MultiMarkdown.

Are there anything like this available.

Thanks

Comment: show some of your code and define markdown and you will get some good help

Comment: Hi Ibu, Markdown is a text to HTML conversion tool. www.daringfireball.net/projects/markdown. I am looking for a parser to the variation of Markdown. There is no code required for this question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js</strike>

My bad, didn't realise MultiMarkDown was a new variation. Currently no JS implementation exists, I'm sure when it does you'll find it on http://search.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

For a Node-based tool to convert MultiMarkdown to HTML, you could take a look at this project:

https://github.com/dtjm/node-multimarkdown